# Kali Linux - Displays -> Could not get screen information

Tags: linux, display, multiple-monitors, kali-linux, display-settings

I just recently installed Kali Linux about a week ago to dual boot alongside my Linux Mint. I have been using Linux Mint for about two years now, but I am new to Kali Linux.

The first day I played around in the Kali Linux Settings and changed the orientation of my monitors because when I **first booted in** the orientation had my **secondary monitor on the right** side **BUT** I have two monitors: my **main monitor** is in **front** of me and my **secondary** is to my **left**. So I opened the Display settings and switched them around no problem.

After installing nvidia drivers following the guide from:

http://docs.kali.org/general-use/install-nvidia-drivers-on-kali-linux

after the **reboot**, my monitors **swapped back to having my secondary monitor on the right** of me. When I opened the display settings to change this back it displays the following:

**"Could not get screen information"**

Can anyone help me to get this working again?

Comment: Can you just swap the cables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now, I heard there was an update on September 13th, 2016 (https:// www.kali.org/news/azure-marketplace-weekly-iso-builds/) for Kali Linux so I just ran:

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

it installed a lot of new updates, I followed it by:

```
apt-get update
```

just for good measure, and after a system reboot everything was working fine again; display settings is able to get screen information on connected monitors now.

Says it's resolved here as well: https:// bugs.kali.org/my_view_page.php

[Could not get screen information resolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yt8iW.png)

[Could not get screen information recently modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGtfO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since I have apt-get dist-upgraded my system today I have the exactly same problem. The built-in monitor works, but I cannot configure it, as well as I cannot manage any secondary displays.

Has anyone got a solution to this problem?

Comment: Please don't leave answers stating that you have the same problem as the one described in the question. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](https://superuser.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.